# How to make Google Chrome Developer tools JavaScript console Variable persistent?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to make a JavaScript variable persistent in chrome developer tools so that it remains available in next page also. For example I want to preserve the `List` variable

```
List = fetchDetails(element)
```

I am working on a simple script which extracts data from a page to the `List` variable. What I need to do is to somehow save this variable so that when I load the next page, and extract information from that page, I am able to append the details to the previously filled list.

```
List2 = fetchDetails(element)
List.push(...List2)
```

In Summary, I need to access the `List` across many pages.

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) might help with that. You can't really make a variable itself presistent across pages, but you can store the value of the variable somewhere and retrieve it later.

Comment: If your goal is to share data between pages, you'll need to use an extension.

Comment: @Ouroborus localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem worked, thanks.